# Finding squares in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

First of all, I've read the other question with similar title, but I'm looking for something more interesting than actually computing squares by hand.

Let $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}/\mathbb{F}_{p}$ be a finite extension of the finite field with $p$ elements.

Is there a general method for finding the subgroup $(\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}^{\times})^{2}$ of squares in the extension?

More generally, is there such a thing for $n$th powers?

Comment: What exactly would your accept as *finding this subgroup*? Do you require a membership test? List the elements? Anyway, if $K=\Bbb{F}_q$, then the group on $n$th powers coincides with the group of $d$th powers, where $d=\gcd(n, q-1)$. And an element $z\in K^*$ is a $d$th power iff $z^{(q-1)/d}=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group $F_{p^n}-\{0\}$ is cyclic, so consider a generator $x$, the squares are the even powers of $x$.